# mysql:Get data at particular time

Tags: mysql

Need suggestion for finding list of all users whose status=1 at 31 jan 23:59:59(end of month).

```
select count(*) from users where status=1 and created_at=?
```

Comment: are status changed now?

Comment: yes @avisheks status can be changed in next month.need to find 31 jan status of all users

Comment: are you maintaining a history of status changes of users somewhere?

Comment: @jacob21 Can you show the table that is storing the status updates?

Comment: Multiple rows for a user..as status changed id,user_id,status,created_at

Comment: I need at jan 31 23:59:59 how many users has status=1

Answer (score 0):

One way you restore your Database to some previous time is reverse running the binlog to current database state.

Or

Start database schema and running all the statement from binlog related to table only.

Take a help of Slave, if its still on some previous state

Answer (score 0):

Below syntax will give any users that have status=1 and that was created on the 31:st of Jan 2014

```
select count(*) 
from users 
where status=1 and DATE(created_at)='2014-01-31'
```

This syntax will give the users that have the exact time '2014-01-31 23:59:59'. Assuming that the dateformat is the same. Seems unlikley that users get created at that time.

```
select count(*) 
    from users 
    where status=1 and created_at='2014-01-31 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Thanks but.i need all users list whose status=1 at 31 jan 2014 23:59:59..need suggestion for that

Comment: No,need different data..need count of users whose status=1 at 2014-01-31 23:59:59 time

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what the syntax will give you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
count(*)
from 
users
where status=1 and 
created_at = concat(last_day(curdate(), ' 23:59:59'));
```

- read more about the `last_day()` function [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day)

Answer (score 0):

If using linux server then schedule below script through cronjob-

Save below lines in user.sh file.

vi user.sh

---

```
#!/bin/bash

DBUSER=your_server_user
DBPASS=your_server_pass

mysql -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASS db_name -e "select count(*) from users where status=1;" >> user.xls

echo -e "Please get the attached user Report." | mail -s"user Report" -a user.xls abc@abc.com
```

---

Now cron this script-

crontab -e

```
59 23 31 1 * /script_path/user.sh
```

It will execute 31, jan at 23:59 and send user report to your mail id.

If you are using windows server then you can create a batch file and call it with the help of Windows Task Schedular.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you mentioned a table which stores historic user updates. You can use this table to check users who had a status of 1 at that time:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS users
FROM status_history sh
WHERE
sh.created = (SELECT MAX(sx.created) 
                     FROM status_history sx
                     WHERE sx.user_id = sh.user_id
                     AND sx.created < '2014-01-31 23:59:59')
AND sh.status = 1
```

We do an inner select to get the latest status change date for each status and user and grab the history with that date. We then count any of those that have status `1`. Obviously if your table schema is different you may need to tweak the above.

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/944800)